# Submit the app for FB review

Tags: ios, facebook

My iOS application is required publish_actions permission from FB, So I have submitted the app for FB review by creating the simulator build as per the instructions [Create simulator build to submit for FB Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/)

But FB team reported an issue that "Your app downloads successfully, but crashes upon opening. Please resolve any technical issues that prevent us from testing your app."

When I try to install the app in my iPhone or any simulator, it was working fine, not sure what was the issue the FB team is facing exactly.

Could anybody suggest what went wrong while testing by FB team.
Can I test the simulator build (.app) which I uploaded in FB by installing in my simulator?

Comment: No, FB just replied with the status message as I mentioned above. "Your app downloads successfully, but crashes upon opening. Please resolve any technical issues that prevent us from testing your app.", Not sure how can I reproduce it at my end

Comment: Try emailing them back and asking for one.  Also make sure you install the *exact* build that you gave them

Comment: As I see, we can't reach directly to the review team as they didn't provide any support email address. Regarding the simulator build installation, can you suggest how can I install .app file in my simulator?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook is using ios-sim to test the simulator build of your applocation. If that build works with ios-sim, then you are good to submit your simulator build for review to Facebook.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Jigar: Thanks for the update! I have followed https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim and I tried to install .app by using reattach-to-user-namespace ios-sim launch /sample.app but it is returning an error "-bash: reattach-to-user-namespace: command not found"

Comment: I could able to install the app after I installed brew and set it up! Now I could able to produce the issue.